# Redirecting to a page with focusing a textarea

Tags: php, html, mysql, css, redirect

On click event i am redirecting to another page.  When it landed on the that page it should focus a textarea at the bottom of that page.  I am trying for long time.  I am working on PHP Platform.  Hope my question clear.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add #focus to the end of your url (ie. http://www.test.com/news/message1#focus.
Then use the code below

```
<a name="focus"><a>
<textarea id="textarea_1">

</textarea>

<script type="text/javascript">
    if ( document.location.hash == '#focus' )
        document.getElementById('textarea_1').focus();
</script>
```

Comment: This script will focus on comment textarea when the page loads.I want the textarea focused only when they click comments in home page

Comment: Adjusted the code for your new requirement. The javascript code will now read the url for #focus at the end. If its there, it will apply the focus.

Comment: Added `<a name="focus"></a>` so you can also be sure the page will scroll down to your textarea when #focus is present.

Comment: The works good.  But it does not place my cursor on the text area.  If i press tab then the cursor coming into my area.

Comment: Does your textarea have the id="textarea_1" ?

Comment: my textarea id is ='textareaid'  i changed id, what you have given.

Comment: Is the order also still the same? The javascript should go below the <textarea> (or added to domReady..)

Answer (score 1):

Give the textarea an `autofocus` attribute, or add javascript that triggers the focus event on it on page load.

```
var textarea = document.getElementsByTagName("textarea")[0];
textarea.focus();
```

Comment: I have a website with news page where.People will read news and comment on same.The News Titles will be displayed in home page and will change on every page refresh. In home page the news Title and comments will be displayed.  When i click the comments in home page news it should take to actual news page and the text area should be focused.